# Why a function in swift can have different argument label and name

Tags: swift

I was going through `Declarations` in Swift at this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html

and one of the lines said, `A parameter has a name, which is used within the function body, as well as an argument label, which is used when calling the function or method. By default, parameter names are also used as argument labels.` i.e.

`(argument label) (parameter name): (parameter type)`

You pass the parameter in this function using `argument label` and use the variable in function using parameter name`

If the function is

`func foo(someVar abc: String)
{
    print(a)
}`

we call it using `foo(someVar: "hello world!")`.

I want to understand the possible reasons behind providing such programming construct

Comment: Saw this - it doesn't answer a concrete reason for doing so.

Comment: @prabodhprakash Yeah it does, the answer makes complete sense.

Comment: Take a look at how Apple uses them.  For example `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int`.  The `numberOfRowsInSection` makes the call read like English, but inside the function the parameter is simply `section`.